# Creating form tooltip is not read by screen reader the first time

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, nvda

I have a component which has 2 parts. The first part is text only with an edit button. Part 2 is another component that edits previous texts - which is another component. Now this part 2 has 1 tool-tip. I have written code inside the `componentDidMount()` hook which opens the tool-tip in the UI but is not read by NVDA the first time.

I have tried using `aria-atomic=true`, `aria-live="assertive"`, and also tried using `aria-labelledby`, but none of these helped.

```
<React.Fragment>
     <div className="tipLabels">{`${personalInfoAddress.firstName.label}:`}</div>
     <Popover popoverContent={personalInfoAddress.firstName.tooltip} target={`member-firstname-${id}`} className="signing-container-tooltip">
          <a id={`member-firstname-${id}`} className="pointer-events helpTipstyle" ref={node => this.tooltip = node} aria-label={`help tooltip ${personalInfoAddress.firstName.tooltip}`} tabIndex="0" role="button">
               <span className="sr-only">{`help tooltip ${personalInfoAddress.firstName.tooltip}`}</span>
               <span className="material-icons align-bottom ml-1" aria-hidden="true">help</span>
          </a>
     </Popover>
</React.Fragment>
```

Tooltip should read by NVDA the first time.

Comment: Sample code is uploaded at [https://github.com/freelancer-polly/tooltip-aoda](https://github.com/freelancer-polly/tooltip-aoda). Run code, use keyboard to navigate to Edit button, click enter, see help gets focussed but NVDA reads nothing. Blur from help and again come back - this time NVDA will read. Need fix for why it is not read for first time?